# Why can't I change the field of view of Oculus Gear VR Headset in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, gear-vr, photosphere, fieldofview

Anytime I edit the camera's field of view in Unity to 100 (instead of the default 60), either Oculus or Unity is limiting the FOV to 60 for my Samsung S7 with Gear VR headset. The 100 is ignored, and 60 is used when using the Gear VR to view the VR app.

Apparently, the support was disabled in March 2017 (or slightly before) to customize the FOV setting of a photosphere in Unity via the camera.

I've heard that the reason you can't change FOV is because it is a device-specific setting (S6 is different that S7, or Oculus Rift is different than Gear VR for Unity camera's FOV value).

Answer (score 0):

> Why?

The word "Virtual Reality" gives the answer to this question.
Just like you can't change fov of your eyes, you shouldn't be able to mess with fov in the app. Depending on device screen (or other factors), they have pre-setup the value so its most resembling to reality.

Moreover there could be other usability problems like VR-Sickness. So Unity took control of this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could also be that the hardware is optimized for a single FOV. Just guessing. Hololens also locks the FOV.

Comment: Perhaps, that could be one.